# Cannot connect kafka server to spark

Tags: apache-spark, apache-kafka, streaming

I try to stream data from kafka server to spark. As you guess I failed. I use spark 2.2.0 and kafka_2.11-0.11.0.1. I loaded jars to eclipse and runned below code.

```
package com.defne

import java.nio.ByteBuffer
import scala.util.Random
import org.apache.spark._
import org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream._
import org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka._
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf
import org.apache.spark.streaming.{Seconds, StreamingContext}
import org.apache.spark.storage.StorageLevel
import org.apache.log4j.Level
import java.util.regex.Pattern
import java.util.regex.Matcher
import kafka.serializer.StringDecoder
import Utilities._
import org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka
import org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka.KafkaUtils

object KafkaExample {

  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    val ssc = new StreamingContext("local[*]", "KafkaExample", Seconds(1))
    val kafkaParams = Map("metadata.broker.list" -> "kafkaIP:9092", "group.id" -> "console-consumer-9526", "zookeeper.connect" -> "localhost:2181")

    val topics = List("logstash_log").toSet
    val lines = KafkaUtils.createDirectStream[String, String, StringDecoder, StringDecoder](ssc, kafkaParams, topics).map(_._2)
    lines.print()


    ssc.checkpoint("C:/checkpoint/")
    ssc.start()
    ssc.awaitTermination()
  }
}
```

And I got below output. Interesting thing is no error exists but somehow I cannot connect to the kafka server.

```
Using Spark's default log4j profile: org/apache/spark/log4j-defaults.properties
17/11/01 10:16:55 INFO SparkContext: Running Spark version 2.2.0
17/11/01 10:16:56 WARN NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
17/11/01 10:16:56 INFO SparkContext: Submitted application: KafkaExample
17/11/01 10:16:56 INFO SecurityManager: Changing view acls to: user
17/11/01 10:16:56 INFO SecurityManager: Changing modify acls to: user
17/11/01 10:16:56 INFO SecurityManager: Changing view acls groups to: 
17/11/01 10:16:56 INFO SecurityManager: Changing modify acls groups to: 
17/11/01 10:16:56 INFO SecurityManager: SecurityManager: authentication disabled; ui acls disabled; users  with view permissions: Set(user); groups with view permissions: Set(); users  with modify permissions: Set(user); groups with modify permissions: Set()
17/11/01 10:16:58 INFO Utils: Successfully started service 'sparkDriver' on port 53749.
17/11/01 10:16:59 INFO SparkEnv: Registering MapOutputTracker
17/11/01 10:16:59 INFO SparkEnv: Registering BlockManagerMaster
17/11/01 10:16:59 INFO BlockManagerMasterEndpoint: Using org.apache.spark.storage.DefaultTopologyMapper for getting topology information
17/11/01 10:16:59 INFO BlockManagerMasterEndpoint: BlockManagerMasterEndpoint up
17/11/01 10:16:59 INFO DiskBlockManager: Created local directory at C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\blockmgr-2fa455d5-ef26-4fb9-ba4b-caf9f2fa3a68
17/11/01 10:16:59 INFO MemoryStore: MemoryStore started with capacity 897.6 MB
17/11/01 10:16:59 INFO SparkEnv: Registering OutputCommitCoordinator
17/11/01 10:16:59 INFO Utils: Successfully started service 'SparkUI' on port 4040.
17/11/01 10:17:00 INFO SparkUI: Bound SparkUI to 0.0.0.0, and started at http://192.168.56.1:4040
17/11/01 10:17:00 INFO Executor: Starting executor ID driver on host localhost
17/11/01 10:17:00 INFO Utils: Successfully started service 'org.apache.spark.network.netty.NettyBlockTransferService' on port 53770.
17/11/01 10:17:00 INFO NettyBlockTransferService: Server created on 192.168.56.1:53770
17/11/01 10:17:00 INFO BlockManager: Using org.apache.spark.storage.RandomBlockReplicationPolicy for block replication policy
17/11/01 10:17:00 INFO BlockManagerMaster: Registering BlockManager BlockManagerId(driver, 192.168.56.1, 53770, None)
17/11/01 10:17:00 INFO BlockManagerMasterEndpoint: Registering block manager 192.168.56.1:53770 with 897.6 MB RAM, BlockManagerId(driver, 192.168.56.1, 53770, None)
17/11/01 10:17:00 INFO BlockManagerMaster: Registered BlockManager BlockManagerId(driver, 192.168.56.1, 53770, None)
17/11/01 10:17:00 INFO BlockManager: Initialized BlockManager: BlockManagerId(driver, 192.168.56.1, 53770, None)
17/11/01 10:17:01 INFO VerifiableProperties: Verifying properties
17/11/01 10:17:01 INFO VerifiableProperties: Property group.id is overridden to console-consumer-9526
17/11/01 10:17:01 INFO VerifiableProperties: Property zookeeper.connect is overridden to localhost:2181
17/11/01 10:17:02 INFO SimpleConsumer: Reconnect due to error:
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.kafka.common.network.NetworkSend.<init>(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/nio/ByteBuffer;)V
    at kafka.network.RequestOrResponseSend.<init>(RequestOrResponseSend.scala:41)
    at kafka.network.RequestOrResponseSend.<init>(RequestOrResponseSend.scala:44)
    at kafka.network.BlockingChannel.send(BlockingChannel.scala:114)
    at kafka.consumer.SimpleConsumer.liftedTree1$1(SimpleConsumer.scala:88)
    at kafka.consumer.SimpleConsumer.kafka$consumer$SimpleConsumer$$sendRequest(SimpleConsumer.scala:86)
    at kafka.consumer.SimpleConsumer.send(SimpleConsumer.scala:114)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka.KafkaCluster$$anonfun$getPartitionMetadata$1.apply(KafkaCluster.scala:126)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka.KafkaCluster$$anonfun$getPartitionMetadata$1.apply(KafkaCluster.scala:125)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka.KafkaCluster$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$streaming$kafka$KafkaCluster$$withBrokers$1.apply(KafkaCluster.scala:346)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka.KafkaCluster$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$streaming$kafka$KafkaCluster$$withBrokers$1.apply(KafkaCluster.scala:342)
    at scala.collection.IndexedSeqOptimized$class.foreach(IndexedSeqOptimized.scala:33)
    at scala.collection.mutable.WrappedArray.foreach(WrappedArray.scala:35)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka.KafkaCluster.org$apache$spark$streaming$kafka$KafkaCluster$$withBrokers(KafkaCluster.scala:342)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka.KafkaCluster.getPartitionMetadata(KafkaCluster.scala:125)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka.KafkaCluster.getPartitions(KafkaCluster.scala:112)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka.KafkaUtils$.getFromOffsets(KafkaUtils.scala:211)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka.KafkaUtils$.createDirectStream(KafkaUtils.scala:484)
    at com.defne.KafkaExample$.main(KafkaExample.scala:44)
    at com.defne.KafkaExample.main(KafkaExample.scala)
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.kafka.common.network.NetworkSend.<init>(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/nio/ByteBuffer;)V
    at kafka.network.RequestOrResponseSend.<init>(RequestOrResponseSend.scala:41)
    at kafka.network.RequestOrResponseSend.<init>(RequestOrResponseSend.scala:44)
    at kafka.network.BlockingChannel.send(BlockingChannel.scala:114)
    at kafka.consumer.SimpleConsumer.liftedTree1$1(SimpleConsumer.scala:101)
    at kafka.consumer.SimpleConsumer.kafka$consumer$SimpleConsumer$$sendRequest(SimpleConsumer.scala:86)
    at kafka.consumer.SimpleConsumer.send(SimpleConsumer.scala:114)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka.KafkaCluster$$anonfun$getPartitionMetadata$1.apply(KafkaCluster.scala:126)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka.KafkaCluster$$anonfun$getPartitionMetadata$1.apply(KafkaCluster.scala:125)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka.KafkaCluster$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$streaming$kafka$KafkaCluster$$withBrokers$1.apply(KafkaCluster.scala:346)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka.KafkaCluster$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$streaming$kafka$KafkaCluster$$withBrokers$1.apply(KafkaCluster.scala:342)
    at scala.collection.IndexedSeqOptimized$class.foreach(IndexedSeqOptimized.scala:33)
    at scala.collection.mutable.WrappedArray.foreach(WrappedArray.scala:35)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka.KafkaCluster.org$apache$spark$streaming$kafka$KafkaCluster$$withBrokers(KafkaCluster.scala:342)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka.KafkaCluster.getPartitionMetadata(KafkaCluster.scala:125)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka.KafkaCluster.getPartitions(KafkaCluster.scala:112)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka.KafkaUtils$.getFromOffsets(KafkaUtils.scala:211)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka.KafkaUtils$.createDirectStream(KafkaUtils.scala:484)
    at com.defne.KafkaExample$.main(KafkaExample.scala:44)
    at com.defne.KafkaExample.main(KafkaExample.scala)
17/11/01 10:17:02 INFO SparkContext: Invoking stop() from shutdown hook
17/11/01 10:17:02 INFO SparkUI: Stopped Spark web UI at http://192.168.56.1:4040
17/11/01 10:17:02 INFO MapOutputTrackerMasterEndpoint: MapOutputTrackerMasterEndpoint stopped!
17/11/01 10:17:02 INFO MemoryStore: MemoryStore cleared
17/11/01 10:17:02 INFO BlockManager: BlockManager stopped
17/11/01 10:17:02 INFO BlockManagerMaster: BlockManagerMaster stopped
17/11/01 10:17:02 INFO OutputCommitCoordinator$OutputCommitCoordinatorEndpoint: OutputCommitCoordinator stopped!
17/11/01 10:17:02 INFO SparkContext: Successfully stopped SparkContext
17/11/01 10:17:02 INFO ShutdownHookManager: Shutdown hook called
17/11/01 10:17:02 INFO ShutdownHookManager: Deleting directory C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\spark-a584950c-10ca-422b-990e-fd1980e2260c
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: According to this link: 
https://community.hortonworks.com/questions/71513/kafkaspout-is-failing-with-nosuchmethoderror-does.html
"NetworkSend constructor has Integer as first argument instead of string, in kafka-1928 it was changed"
Make sure you added all the required dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

### NOTE

Add hostname:port for Kafka brokers, not Zookeeper

```
import kafka.serializer.StringDecoder
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf
import org.apache.spark.streaming.{Seconds, StreamingContext}
import org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka.KafkaUtils

     val ssc = new StreamingContext(new SparkConf, Seconds(60))

  // hostname:port for Kafka brokers, not Zookeeper
     val kafkaParams = Map("metadata.broker.list" -> "localhost:9092,anotherhost:9092")

     val topics = Set("sometopic", "anothertopic")

     val stream = KafkaUtils.createDirectStream[String, String, StringDecoder, StringDecoder](ssc, kafkaParams, topics)
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. I was already using kafka IP.  I changed my code according to yours. But no response. Still same error. I wonder wheter my jar files are wrong. Can you share a link for correct jars?